# Would video buffing speed mean anything when using TOR?

Tags: onion-services

I was browsing on TOR the other day and watching videos on TOR. Normally from my experience, videos load very slow on TOR but this specific website was loading my videos at a fast speed. It raised a few red flags because I am scared that I might've stumbled upon a honeypot setup by a hacker. I did not give out any personal information or create an account. I browsed the website as a guest. I am a bit scared that by clicking and viewing the video, the video might've deployed a malware onto my computer and that the hidden service itself could've leaked my IP address. Sorry if I sound like an amateur, I am sort of new to using TOR so I am a bit paranoid. FYI, the contents of the website are legal.

Answer (score 3):

Relays in the Tor network have varying CPU and networking performance. This means that the throughput of a circuit depends on the performance of the relays in the circuit. Some circuits will be slower and others will be faster. Having a video that loads quickly does not indicate any kind of attack, and you just may be accessing the website over a circuit using fast relays.

Answer (score 0):

It's **just** a question of network paths and speeds on each step of them. Basically - in clearnet case the key difference **is the only fact** that the signal path is straight and open to the observer. All the other issues with a path segment speed, load ant throughput are exactly the same

- In *clearnet case* you have dependency on the network channels speed, load, switches and routers' CPU loads et cetera...
- In *Tor case* you have exactly the same issues as in clearnet case, because Tor is built on the top of it - and additionally the nodes involved in your path are also have their CPU loads, RAM speeds, Network speeds e.t.c.

..... so you was not compromised for sure! You was just unlucky when you've had a slow speed and long buffering - and your request went fine when you have had a fast experience